# getJson parser doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Hi I am trying to parser the json response of the url but i am not able to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600', function(data) {
        alert (c.email);
    });
});
```

In this page there is my code http://pastie.org/3379735

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Always include the code in your question. Two problems I see: If the Google APIs don't support JSONP, you are out of luck. If they do, you probably have to add `callback=?` as URL parameter. You don't have `c` defined anywhere, the parameter name of the callback is `data`.

Comment: @FelixKling is right about the callback

Answer (score 2):

What is c.email, think you want data.email

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3600&callback=?', function(data) {

    alert (data.email);

  });
});
```

**Update**

as the OP has now stated after reading the documentation you need to provied the callback for jsonp as part of the path, not the params in the form of

```
https://oauth2-login-demo.appspot.com/oauthcallback?code={authorizationCode}
```

docs can be found [here](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.html#handlingresponse)

Comment: Does `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo...` return JSONP? If yes, how does jQuery know about it in this case? I don't think this will work.

Comment: true, updated answer, but you still need to call the correct variable within the getJSON block!

Comment: The question still remains: Does this API support JSONP? If not, adding `callback=?` won't help.

Comment: The url return me this: {
 "email": "xxxxxxxxxx",
 "verified_email": true
}                                                                    if I put ...&callback=data...it prints me "null"

Comment: @uto: Then it does not seem to support JSONP.

Comment: yes it support JsonP....the problem is that i have to put callback in the request...http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2Login.html#handlingresponse....

Comment: sorry @uto but i dont have time to figure that out for you.. sorry not to be of help if i have time later i will have a look..

Comment: @uto [This page](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html) in the google docs might help you; it describes authorization codes in the context of OAuth2.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction you cannot send cross domain AJAX requests. There's no JSONP support for this so you cannot directly access his url from your code.

You may take a look at the [following demo](http://gwt-oauth2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/script/ScriptSample.html) based on the [gwt-oauth2.js](http://gwt-oauth2.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/script/gwt-oauth2.js) script which uses [this code](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-oauth2/source/browse/trunk/samples/script/ScriptSample.html) to authenticate with Google.